# Tkinter - loop a funcion while updating it in the GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I loop a function that displays a value in my window?

So I have this function from telethon to get all the new messages from telegram:

```
def get_message():
    for message in client.iter_messages('@snoopdoggystyledogg', limit=10):
        msg_history = utils.get_display_name(message.sender), message.message
        return msg_history
```

And I have this to display it:

```
messages = Text(root)
messages.insert(INSERT, '')
messages.insert(INSERT, get_message())

messages.pack()
```

But the problem is that the messages doesn't get updated if I'm not reopening the app.. Any idea how to make it loop and update it on my chat screen?

Comment: Put the code to update the Text box in a function, and use a Button to call the function or the `after` method to call the function on a schedule.

Comment: Agree with @Novel. Its a simple fix that can be done with a button or a timed loop using the `after()` method. If its a live feed I would use the `after()` method to check if there is a new message and if the message is new then pull message and insert it to your textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `after()` to continue the loop.

A simple example would be the following:

```
from tkinter import *
# other imports for your client message reader


root = Tk()

def get_message():
    for message in client.iter_messages('@snoopdoggystyledogg', limit=10):
        msg_history = utils.get_display_name(message.sender), message.message
        messages.insert(INSERT, msg_history)
    root.after(5000, get_message)

messages = Text(root)
messages.pack()
messages.insert(INSERT, '')
get_message()

root.mainloop()
```

I think the problem you may need to fix is tracking the last message or last messages so you don't reload old ones.